# How to use NancyFX in a pre-existing WCF project?

Tags: wcf, nancy

Is possible to use NancyFX in a pre-existent WCF project? The idea is to run wcf endpoints side-by-side with nancy endpoints.

I tried official [nancy guide](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-wcf) but it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing?* - your question is "missing" clarity

Comment: Please, can you share some of the code?